# Folders missing in project pane in Webstorm

Tags: ide, webstorm

I've built a project in WebStorm and then submitted the project to GitHub.

When I rebooted the computer and relaunched WebStorm (and the project), all I can see in the project pane is the root files, and none of the folders (yes the folders are there)

See the image below for reference.

Does anyone know how I can get those folders to re-appear in the project pane of Webstorm?

[image]

Answer (score 121, accepted):

It can be caused by the corrupted `.idea/modules.xml` project file. You can either try to fix it manually (restore from Local History, version control or backup) or create the new project from scratch.

[Check this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-8692) for the hints/workarounds.

Comment: Yup, just got an email back from Jetbrains. I had to do a terminal command `$ rm -r .idea` then open the directory in Webstorm. This rebuilt the project for me.

Comment: in fact, I got the email from you ;-) Thanks for the help and direction.

Comment: I was able to just delete the `modules.xml` file. It saved the rest of the project settings, which was welcome.

Comment: Sometimes, only `restarting IDE` helps!

Comment: For me, manually deleting .idea file didn't work but doing rm -rf did. Weird.

Comment: @dasfdsa a little late now, but it's because it's a folder not a file.

Answer (score 102):

It happens sometimes in WebStorm 9.
The easiest way to fix it for me:

1. close WebStorm;
2. in project's folder remove .idea/ (hidden directory);
3. open your project, enjoy:)

Comment: so you're just repeating what the accepted answer states... 3 years later? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9302503/124069 (read the comments)

Comment: @ChaseFlorell in accepted answer you have to read comments, check links (spend extra time). This answer provides 3 simple steps and off you go.

Comment: I'm trying this but not getting any result in the latest Webstorm version 2021.1.1. anyone have faced the same? I just can't see the files in my project.

Answer (score 11):

### Solution:

---

### Creating a new project from existing sources

1. File => New => Project
2. Select "Empty Project"
3. Browse to the location of your project with folder issues
4. Click "Create"
5. Select "Create from Existing Sources" in the "Directory Is Not Empty" dialog

### Why this solution:

---

Editing and deleting in various combinations of .idea and XML files did not solve the issue for me. Hence the solution above. Back up your .idea directory in case you have project customizations you want to keep. This likely overwrites them.

### Outcome:

---

All the various folders I had created were now visible and the project worked as expected. The .idea directory was now formatted correctly with all the necessary files.

Answer (score 8):

Find the .idea/modules.xml in your project root
make sure that these lines are correct :

```
<modules>
  <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/.idea/NameOfYourProject.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/.idea/NameOfYourProject.iml" />
</modules>
```

Replace NameOfYourProject.iml with the name of your project.

Then, make sure that the file .idea/NameOfYourProject.iml exists, if not , create it and put this in it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="WEB_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager">
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$" />
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="module-library">
      <library name="PHP">
        <CLASSES>
          <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../php/PEAR" />
        </CLASSES>
        <SOURCES />
      </library>
    </orderEntry>
  </component>
</module>
```

Comment: Thanks, creating the new project was quick and painless.

Comment: For me `NameOfYourProject.iml` was pointing to the wrong file. Updating it to the correct file name fixed my issue and I didn't lose any settings.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to delete whole .idea folder and reconfigure your whole project, just

1. delete the .idea/modules.xml
2. restart the IDE and your folders are there again!

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue and resolved it by invalidating the cache. 
The option is under File > Invalidate Caches/Restart.
On the prompt click Invalidate and restart.

Note: The project in concern needs to be open before you do this.

Answer (score 3):

I see this from time to time. I use Git, and I have my .gitignore file set up as [recommended](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems), specifically:

```
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/*.iml
```

I sometimes see this after cloning the repository, and when trying to figure out why, I came across this post and read the accepted answer.

I deleted the `modules.xml` file and reopened WebStorm (2016.2.4), and it was resolved. I looked at the new `modules.xml` and found that its contents were exactly the same as before, but my `<projectName>.iml` file was bigger.

So it seems to be a corruption in the `.iml` file, not `modules.xml`. I assume that deleting `modules.xml` triggers a rebuild of the `.iml` file. Not sure if this helps anyone with anything, but thought I would offer the extra insight.

Answer (score 1):

floor 36  solve my problem. in WebStrorm 11

It happens sometimes in WebStorm 9. The easiest way to fix it for me:

1. close WebStorm;
2. in project's folder remove .idea/ (hidden directory);
3. open your project, enjoy:)

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting workspace.xml and watchertask.xml then just restart the IDE. You must see your full source code in all folders there.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the culprit, it was **`Team Foundation Server - Version Control Integration`** plugin from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7961-team-foundation-server--version-control-integration/

I looked at the **`system/log/idea.log`** file and found that this plugin was producing Null exception whenever I open a new folder as a new project and breaks the **`content root`** auto detection by the IDE, and after I uninstalled this plugin, all folders show up as it should.

You might have this issue because of a culprit plugin, and disabling those which you have just installed recently just before  this issue occurs, will resolve the issue. Check the log file and search for `ERROR`.

If it is found to be an important plugin you are actively using which you are not willing to disable, then a temporary fix is to open **`Settings->Directories`** and click **`Add content root`** button to add the root folder of your project, click **`Ok`** now folders will show up and indexing will begin, and of course you have to do this everytime you open a new folder as new project.