# Why do Folder- and File-names in WebStorm project explorer disappear?

Tags: webstorm

As I work with WebStorm (on Windows 10) I see folders and files in the project explorer without their name showing, see picture below. If I click on such a file or folder the name appears but typically then the name of some other file or folder in the same view goes blank.

It makes programming difficult, it's hard to find a file or folder if you can't see their names. Is there a way to fix this by adjusting some memory settings perhaps, or something?

[image: Missing Folder- and File-names in WebStorm]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Folders missing in project pane in Webstorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302346/folders-missing-in-project-pane-in-webstorm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue unfortunately, see [IDEA-101953](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101953) and linked tickets.. Issue is being worked on, but it's is a complicated task and requires some time